# generic array of inner class initialization in java

Tags: java, arrays, generics, inner-classes

Is there any way to make the following code work in Java?

```
public class RandomizedQueue<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {  
    private static final int ARRAYSIZE = 8; // default array size
    private Node[] nodeArray;               // contains pointers to the randomized nodes    
    private int size;                       // current size of queue

    private class Node
    {
        private Item item;
        private Node next;
        private Node previos;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public RandomizedQueue()           // construct an empty randomized queue
    {
        nodeArrays = (Node[]) new Object[ARRAYSIZE]; // fix this and everything works!
    }

    // unimportant randomized queue implementation details
    // ...
}
```

It crashes on runtime at nodeArray initialization line with the following error:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: [Ljava.lang.Object; cannot be cast to [LRandomizedQueue$Node;
    at RandomizedQueue.<init>(RandomizedQueue.java:18)
    at Subset.main(Subset.java:6)`.

The problem is that I cannot use library data structures such as ArrayList<>, because I got to have custom re-size rules. In addition, I cannot implement ArrayList analogue myself (no additional classes allowed in my task).

Code `nodeArray = new Node[ARRAYSIZE];` does not compile in Eclipse with error `Cannot create a generic array of RandomizedQueue<Item>.Node`.

Comment: Why not `Node[] nodeArrays = new Node[ARRAYSIZE];` ?

Comment: You're storing it as `Node[]`, why initialize it as `Object[]`?

Comment: If you could give ArrayList custom resize rules, could you use it then?

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Initializer's part looked like this:
nodeArrays = (Node[]) new Object[ARRAYSIZE]; (no local variable)

Comment: Bohemian: yes, it would be sufficient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the parametrization of inner class Node as well.

```
class RandomizedQueue<Item> implements Iterable<Item> {
private static final int ARRAYSIZE = 8; // default array size
private Node[] nodeArray; // contains pointers to the randomized nodes
private int size; // current size of queue

private class Node<Item> {
    private Item k;
    private Node next;
    private Node previos;

}

public RandomizedQueue() // construct an empty randomized queue
{
    super();
    nodeArray = new Node[ARRAYSIZE];
}

@Override
public Iterator<Item> iterator() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

[image: Inner Class]

Comment: Does not compile in Eclipse. I have tried this way too before asking.

Comment: I am able to do this in Eclipse. See the attached screenshot.

Comment: NO. This is BAD. You are declaring a non-static inner class `Node`, which is in the scope of the outer `Item`, yet you parameterize it again with a parameter with the same name `Item`, therefore hiding it. So you have two completely separate things named `Item`.

Comment: @newacct, It was taken to make the understanding easier. See the screenshot I have attached.

Comment: So what's the point of parameterizing `Node`, when it is already within the parameterization of the outer class?

Comment: Agreed. But if you don't parameterize the inner class you cannot instantiate an array which seems to be requirement. If the inner class was static then this was not required. I do not know what prompted this decision of having private non static inner class and an array of it, but if you have to satisfy this, then you have to parametrize the Inner class Node.

Answer (score 2):

YOur problem is with this:

public class RandomizedQueue implements Iterable {
        [...]
        private class Node
        {
            private Item item;

Firstly, you probably want to be using a [static] nested class rather than an inner class. `Item` is a generic parameter, which isn't obvious because you are not using the standard coding conventions. `Node` needs a generic argument. So:

public class RandomizedQueue implements Iterable {
        [...]
        private static class Node {
            private U item;

So now you're wanting an array of these `Node<U>`s. Normally, I'd say use a `List<Node<U>>`, but I assume you're trying for some kind of low level efficiency here. So we need to make a dodgy array of the rawtype and cast on the generics.

```
       Node<T>[] nodeArrays = (Node<T>[])new Node[ARRAYSIZE];
```

Assuming you actually want to assign directly to the field:

```
       nodeArrays = (Node<T>[])new Node[ARRAYSIZE];
```

Probably a better way is to make `Node` non-generic and then cast on "gets".

```
    private static class Node {
       [...]
       Node[] nodeArrays = new Node[ARRAYSIZE];
    [...]
    private T at(int index) {
        return (T)nodeArrays[index];
    }
```

BTW: If you are going to suppress warnings, only suppress over a single line. This may require introducing a temporary variable.

Comment: It looks like a good idea, but this code does not compiles for me in Eclipse. Does it work for you? May be I have misunderstood you, so if you have this code working, can you send me in private message (or here, if you wish) whole class (with proper inner Node class definition and node array's initialization)?

Answer (score 1):

`Node` is a non-static inner class, which means it is within the scope of the outer class's generic parameters, and which also means that it is *implicitly parameterized* with the outer class's generic parameters.

Inside `RandomizedQueue`, `Node` means `RandomizedQueue<Item>.Node`. That means it is a parameterized type. You cannot create arrays of parameterized types in Java. You can only create arrays of raw types or wildcard-parameterized types.

So what is the raw type of `Node`? (It is not just `Node` as I explained earlier.) You must explicitly qualify it with the outer class name: `RandomizedQueue.Node`.

So the solution is to create an array of the raw type:

```
nodeArrays = (Node[]) new RandomizedQueue.Node[ARRAYSIZE];
```

or of the wildcard-parameterized type:

```
nodeArrays = (Node[]) new RandomizedQueue<?>.Node[ARRAYSIZE];
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be doing this.

```
Node[] nodeArrays = new Node[ARRAYSIZE];
```

Comment: @kocko It would work even if `Node` is an interface. You can of course create an array of interface. However, you cannot fill it with instances of interface, but only classes implementing the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Don't create local variable `Node[] nodeArrays = (Node[]) new Object[ARRAYSIZE];`  within `RandomizedQueue()` constructor.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public RandomizedQueue()           
{
     nodeArray = new Node[ARRAYSIZE]; Now This is fixed 
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question, it was not local variable in the first place. In addition, I have tried to initialize my array this way, but it does not compile in Eclipse: Cannot create a generic array of RandomizedQueue<Item>.Node